# Sending soap xml on Oracle

Tags: xml, oracle, soap

How can i send followed soap xml on Oracle.I found a couple topic about this issue but i dont solve this issue according by specified topics.Actually i want to send this message most basicly.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <registerFor xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <composite xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ServiceWcf" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <a:AppKey>456DSFSDFDS789DSFSDFSDF</a:AppKey>
                <a:AppSecret>SDFSDF7894DSF465DSF46546DSFSDF</a:AppSecret>
                <a:args xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
                    <b:KeyValueOfstringanyType>
                        <b:Key>username</b:Key>
                        <b:Value i:type="c:string" xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">mjora</b:Value>
                    </b:KeyValueOfstringanyType>
                    <b:KeyValueOfstringanyType>
                        <b:Key>body</b:Key>
                        <b:Value i:type="c:string" xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">Message detail</b:Value>
                    </b:KeyValueOfstringanyType>
                </a:args>
            </composite>
        </registerFor>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two common ways:

- using plain PL/SQL and [UTL_HTTP](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/u_http.htm#CHDIAFFA) package to send request;
- using [UTL_DBWS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_dbws.htm) package to interact with document-style service on SOAP level.

There are many examples on the web for both cases, even on StackOverflow ( [serach-1](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=oracle+utl_http+soap), [serach-2](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=oracle+utl_dbws) ) and it's too generic topic to post full explanation in answer.